# ¿Cómo contar días entre rangos de fechas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente inquietud, necesito hacer la suma total de días ejecutados en las actividades de un caso, donde cada actividad tiene una fecha de inicio y una fecha final, pero debo tener en cuenta que si una o varias de las actividades del caso se ejecuto en un rango de fechas similar o dentro de otro rango, claramente estos días no deben sumar como se muestra en la siguiente matriz de ejemplo

ticketnumber | fechainicio | fechafin |  cantidaddias

73252-1 | 2018-04-09 |2018-04-11| 3

**73252-2 | 2018-04-09  | 2018-04-10|  2**

73252-3  | 2018-04-12 |2018-04-16|   5

Donde se evidencia que el soporte tuvo 3 actividades y dicho esto suman entre todas 10 días, pero la activad dos se encuentra en un rango de similar o menor a la fecha de inicio y fecha final de la actividad uno, por eso esos dos días no deben sumar quedando  como días total de ejecución del caso en tan solo 8

Comment: Lo que creo que deberias de hacer es buscar la fecha de inicio menor y la fecha fin mayor y sacar la diferencia de días sin importar cuantos registros tengas entre estas fechas.

Comment: Bienvenido Ricardo Medina a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. En cuanto a tu pregunta, creo que lo fundamental es saber si existen intervalos de tiempo sin actividad entre la primer y última actividad, en caso que no pudieran existir días libres  el comentario anterior te serviría como solución.

Comment: intente probar ese método pero me fallan en el momento en el que supongamos haya una brecha de tiempo entre las actividades, basado en la casuística de los casos puede ser que hayan tiempos muertos entre las actividades.  se me ocurre o creo que podría diseñar un bucle dinámico o algo por el estilo, mil gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Podrias compartir el código con lo que has intentando y los resultados, porque ante la situación de tener puntos muertos entre fechas, no encuentro forma de hacerlo desde una sola consulta, lo que se me ocurre es cambiar la forma en que creas los registros en esa tabla cada vez que vayas a insertar verifiques si existe un registro entre esas fechas para que sepas de ese rango cuantos días ya no deberias de contabilizar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con una tabla temporal voy recorriendo fila a fila tomando la fecha de creación y la fecha fin, acumulo la diferencia de días más uno para contar también la fecha de creación, borro todos los registros que estén entre las fechas que acabamos de seleccionar y sigo con mi ciclo:

```
CREATE TABLE #tablaTemporal( 
 ticketnumber VARCHAR(max),
 fechacreacion DATETIME,
 fechafin DATETIME,
 cantidaddias INT
)

INSERT INTO #tablaTemporal VALUES 
    ('73252-1', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-11', 3), 
    ('73252-2', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-10', 2), 
    ('73252-3', '2018-04-12', '2018-04-16', 5)

DECLARE @CONTADOR INT, @ACUMULADOR INT = 0, @FECHACREACION DATETIME, @FECHAFIN DATETIME
SELECT @CONTADOR = COUNT(*) FROM #tablaTemporal

WHILE (@CONTADOR > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @FECHACREACION = fechacreacion, @FECHAFIN = fechafin 
    FROM #tablaTemporal
    WHERE ticketnumber LIKE '%73252%' ORDER BY fechacreacion, fechafin DESC

    SET @ACUMULADOR = @ACUMULADOR + DATEDIFF(DAY, @FECHACREACION, @FECHAFIN) + 1

    DELETE FROM #tablaTemporal 
    WHERE fechacreacion >= @FECHACREACION 
    AND fechafin <= @FECHAFIN
    AND ticketnumber LIKE '%73252%'

    SELECT @CONTADOR = COUNT(*) FROM #tablaTemporal
END

SELECT @ACUMULADOR AS 'Resultado'

DROP TABLE #tablaTemporal
```

Mi respuesta anterior y esta son válidas la razón por la que no me daba el resultado que esperabas tiene que ver con la función DateDiff.

Si realizas estos querys te darás cuenta de lo que hablo:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (DAY, '2018-04-09', '2018-04-11') --DEVUELVE 2 Y DEBERÍA SER 3
SELECT DATEDIFF (DAY, '2018-04-09', '2018-04-10') --DEVUELVE 1 Y DEBERÍA SER 2
SELECT DATEDIFF (DAY, '2018-04-12', '2018-04-16') --DEVUELVE 4 Y DEBERÍA SER 5
SELECT DATEDIFF (DAY, '2018-04-12', '2018-04-12') --DEVUELVE 0 Y DEBERÍA SER 1
```

Lo que pasa es que la función lo que hace es sacar las diferencias mas no lleva un conteo, por lo que para que funcione de la manera que quieres solo hay que sumarle 1 a esa diferencia.

**Límites de datepart**

Las instrucciones siguientes tienen los mismos valores startdate y enddate. Esas fechas son adyacentes y tienen una diferencia horaria de 0,0000001 segundos. La diferencia entre startdate y enddate en cada instrucción cruza un límite de calendario u hora de su datepart. Cada instrucción devuelve 1. Si startdate y enddate tienen valores de año diferentes pero tienen los mismos valores de semana del calendario, DATEDIFF devolverá 0 para datepart week.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,        '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(quarter,     '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,       '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(dayofyear,   '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,         '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(week,        '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,        '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,      '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,      '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, '2005-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', '2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000');
```

Se saca es la diferencia entre fecha y fecha por lo que lógicamente a esa diferencia hay que sumarle uno para que te cuente la fecha inicio, en conclusión con el query de esta manera debería funcionarte:

```
CREATE TABLE #tablaTemporal( 
 ticketnumber VARCHAR(max),
 fechacreacion DATETIME,
 fechafin DATETIME,
 cantidaddias INT
)

INSERT INTO #tablaTemporal VALUES 
    ('73252-1', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-11', 3), 
    ('73252-2', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-10', 2), 
    ('73252-3', '2018-04-12', '2018-04-16', 5)

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(fechacreacion), MAX(fechafin)) + 1 AS 'Resultado'
FROM #tablaTemporal 
WHERE ticketnumber LIKE '%73252%'

DROP TABLE #tablaTemporal
```

Si me tocará decidir entre uno y otro query preferiría el primero por que respetaría los huecos que puedan existir entre fechas, el segundo query te funcionaría solo si las fechas son corridas y no hay huecos.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta no es funcional del todo.

Comment: Ya ajuste la respuesta, mi respuesta anterior también servia pero encontré algo en la documentación sobre el DateDiff que me afectaba el query.

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por el apoyo brindado, he realizado varias pruebas con las propuestas realizadas y el modelo presentado por Víctor Perdomo se ajusto bastante a la solución que estaba buscando, mil gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

La idea inicial de contar los días desde la primera de las fechas de inicio hasta la última de las fechas de fin sería buena sino fuera por que existen o podrían existir huecos de actividad en ese rango de fechas.

Entendiendo que lo que podríamos hacer entonces es:

1. Contar los días totales desde el inicio hasta el fín
2. Contar los días que no tienen actividad
3. Restar 1 y 2 para obtener en definitiva los días de actividad

Los puntos 1 y 2 son triviales de resolver, el punto 2 es un poco más complejo, necesitamos tener una "tabla" con cada una de las fechas en el conjunto total de días. Siempre es bueno tener un tabla física con esta información, pero si no la tenemos se puede generar al vuelo mediante alguna técnica para generar numeraciones, en SQL server lamentablemente no tenemos una pseudo tabla como `dual` de Oracle o una función de generación de secuencias, así que hay que inventar algo.

En primer lugar definamos un ejemplo de datos:

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE ( 
    ticketnumber    VARCHAR(255),
    fechacreacion   DATETIME,
    fechafin        DATETIME,
    cantidaddias    INT
)

INSERT INTO @Ejemplo (ticketnumber, fechacreacion, fechafin, cantidaddias) 
VALUES 
    ('73252-1', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-11', 3), 
    ('73252-2', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-10', 2), 
    ('73252-3', '2018-04-15', '2018-04-19', 5)
```

Es un poco distinto al tuyo, simplemente hemos agregado un hueco de actividad en los días 12 al 14. En total son 11 días, del 9 al 19 y el hueco de actividad es de 3 días, es decir que el total de días de activida será de 8 días.

Para resolver esto, hay que hacer uso de algunas variables intermedias y lo que te comentaba, un generador de secuencia para poder tener todos los días desde el 9 al 19 y verificar si cada uno de estos cae dentro de un rango de actividad, sino será un día sin actividad.

```
SELECT  @DiasSinActividad = COUNT(1)
    FROM (  SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, @FechaInicio) AS Fecha
        FROM (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.N) Number
            FROM (SELECT 0 AS 'N' UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS 'N' UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS 'N' UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) T3
        ) AS n(Number)
        WHERE DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, @FechaInicio) <= @FechaFin
    ) F
    LEFT JOIN @Ejemplo E
        ON F.Fecha >= E.fechacreacion
        AND F.Fecha <= E.fechafin
    WHERE ticketnumber IS NULL

SELECT  @TotalDias - @DiasSinActividad
```

Importante: La generación del rango de fecha de este ejemplo estaría limitada a 1.000 días, si quieres incrementarla a 10.000, 100.000, 1.000.000, etc, debes duplicar cada vez un `CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS 'N' UNION SELECT 1 ...) Tn`